# Unable to connect to remote host: ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.2 port 22: Connection refused

Tags: docker, ssh

I'm currently learning Docker and I'm doing an exercice which involves connecting to a remote server, which is located in a Docker container, from another container which uses Jenkins through SSH.

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y install openssh-server && \
        yum install -y passwd && \
        yum install -y initscripts

RUN useradd remote_user && \
    echo "1234" | passwd remote_user  --stdin && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh

COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN chown remote_user:remote_user   -R /home/remote_user && \
    chmod 400 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN ssh-keygen -A

RUN yum -y install mysql


CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

And this my Docker-compose:

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: romantic_dhawan
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "$PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
    networks:
      - net
  remote_host:
    container_name: remote-host
    image: remote-host
    build:
      context: centos7
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
```

Both containers are up and running as you can see if I type docker ps:

[Docker PS prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vURyI.png)

or in the Desktop app:

[Desktop App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdNjQ.png)

Forgot to mention: I'm using a Macbook Por for this exercice.

Can you help me? I'm stuck with this and can't progress through the course.

First I connect to Jenkins container with

`docker exec -it romantic_dhawan bash` 
and then try to connect to the remote host using:

`ssh remote_user@remote_host`

and get this error: ssh: Could not resolve hostname remote_host: Name or service not known

Also tried with "remote-host".

However, if I try using the IP address I get this error:

`ssh: connect to host 172.17.0.2 port 22: Connection refused`

**UPDATE:**

I just saw there is no sshd file in the path specified in the dockerfile: `CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D` as you can see in the pic (at the left the path in the Dockerfile and at the right the files which are in /usr/sbin/):

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHw2t.png)

As you can see, it's missing inside sbin. Could be this the problem? I tried to look for the way to get that file in Google without success.

Comment: You use `docker exec` to connect to container's shell, not SSH server. You can SSH to the _external_ host where Docker daemon runs.

Comment: "Could not resolve hostname" has nothing to do with SSH though, refer networking docs - https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: When you get "connection refused" this means that either the sshd is not running, the sshd port is closed, or the user does not let you log in. Which users are declared in your sshd container?